# Create List[List[String]] from a text file separated by blank lines (using Regex)

Tags: regex, scala, sed, awk

The content of the file is here: http://pastebin.com/nAe9q9Kt (as I cannot have multiple blank lines in a question)

Below is a screenshot from my sublime-text.

[image]

SPACED INPUT EXAMPLE START

```
a

b


c
```

SPACED INPUT EXAMPLE END

You can notice that most of the lines `begin with 0(zero), except the words ENGINEERS and DOESNT` and `are separated by single blank line and sometimes by double blank lines.`

Basically what I want is this:

```
List(
  List("0MOST PEOPLE", "0BELIEVE", "0THAT"),
  List("0IF IT", "0AINT BROKE", "0DONT FIX IT"),
  List("0BELIEVE", "0THAT", "0IF", "0IT AINT BROKE"),
  List("0IT"),
  List("0HAVE", "0ENOUGH", "0FEATURES YET.")
)
```

I tried to write a tail-recursive code and it worked well in the end :) But it takes too long (a couple of minutes) to run on a huge file (which has more than 10K lines)

I thought of using Regex approach or execute Unix commands like sed or awk through Scala code to generate a temp file. My guess is that it will run faster than my current approach.

Can somebody please help me with the Regex ?

Here is my tail-recursive Scala code:

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec
  def inner(remainingLines: List[String], previousLineIsBlank: Boolean, frames: List[List[String]], frame: List[String]): List[List[String]] = {
    remainingLines match {
      case Nil => frame :: frames

      case line :: Nil if !previousLineIsBlank =>
        inner(
          remainingLines = Nil,
          previousLineIsBlank = false,
          frames = frame :: frames,
          frame = line :: frame)

      case line :: tail => {
        line match {
          case "" if previousLineIsBlank => // Current line is blank, previous line is blank
            inner(
              remainingLines = tail,
              previousLineIsBlank = true,
              frames = frame :: frames,
              frame = List.empty[String])
          case "" if !previousLineIsBlank => // Current line is blank, previous line is not blank
            inner(
              remainingLines = tail,
              previousLineIsBlank = true,
              frames = frames,
              frame = frame)
          case line if !line.startsWith("0") && previousLineIsBlank => // Current line is not blank and does not start with 0 (ENGINEER, DOESN'T), previous line is blank
            inner(
              remainingLines = tail,
              previousLineIsBlank = false,
              frames = frames,
              frame = frame)
          case line if previousLineIsBlank => // Current line is not blank and does starts with 0, previous line is blank
            inner(
              remainingLines = tail,
              previousLineIsBlank = false,
              frames = frames,
              frame = line :: frame)
          case line if !previousLineIsBlank => // Current line is not blank, previous line not is blank
            inner(
              remainingLines = tail,
              previousLineIsBlank = false,
              frames = frames,
              frame = line :: frame)
          case line => sys.error("Unmatched case = " + line)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: @jaypal: Because I want to select and process the text. In the end I want to run this Unix command in my Scala code.

Comment: Please edit your question to properly format the sample input and expected output.

Comment: @EdMorton: Just learnt that images can be uploaded :) I formatted the output too.

Comment: We can't copy/paste images to run test scripts on so posting an image of your sample input isn't nearly as useful as posting the text of your actual sample input.

Comment: @EdMorton I tried to post the text as it is but Stackoverflow formatting for blank lines and double blank lines wasn't just the same as my actual text. Please suggest a way. I tried double quotes, ticks, and several other special symbols to make sure that that I show blank lines as per my original text.

Comment: @EdMorton Just found that I can show only a max of 1 blank line between lines on Stackoverflow.

Comment: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) might be a better solution.

Comment: @CAustin Thank you. Added the link in the body of the question.

Comment: @VenkatSudheerReddyAedama You can treat your input like a block of code (indent it all four spaces) to get it to format similar to how you typed it.

Comment: Can you tell us the rules on how to print `,` and `.`?

Comment: @VenkatSudheerReddyAedama You can put in as many blank likes as you like. See the example I added after your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val source = """0MOST PEOPLE
0BELIEVE
0THAT


0IF IT
0AINT BROKE,
0DONT FIX IT.


ENGINEERS

0BELIEVE
0THAT
0IF
0IT AINT BROKE,


0IT

DOESNT

0HAVE
0ENOUGH
0FEATURES YET."""

val output = (for (s <- source.split("\n\n").toList) yield {   // split on empty lines
            s.split("\n").toList                      // split on new lines 
            .filter(_.headOption.getOrElse("")=='0')}  // get rid of entries not starting with '0'
    ).filter(!_.isEmpty)                              // get rid of possible empty blocks

//output formatted for readability
scala> output: List[List[String]] = List(List(0MOST PEOPLE, 0BELIEVE, 0THAT), 
                                         List(0IF IT, 0AINT BROKE,, 0DONT FIX IT.),
                                         List(0BELIEVE, 0THAT, 0IF, 0IT AINT BROKE,), 
                                         List(0IT), 
                                         List(0HAVE, 0ENOUGH, 0FEATURES YET.))
```

UPDATE:
if you are reading the lines from file, then the old imperative approach might work quite well, especially if source file is large:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
val lb = ListBuffer[List[String]]()
val ml = ListBuffer[String]()
for (ll <- source.fromFile(<yourfile>)) {
    if (ll.isEmpty) { 
        if (!ml.isEmpty) lb += ml.toList 
        ml.clear
    } else if (ll(0)=='0') ml+=ll 
}
val output = lb.toList
```

Comment: You made the input a String. But it is a file in my case. So I did scala.io.Source.fromFile(new java.io.File("fileName")).getLines.toList. I got the list of strings now.. converting that to String using mkString method on List yields a String with empty String for blank lines. Cant do a split on "\n\n" anymore.. cant do a split on double space because the text may have double spaces too

Comment: You can convert it to String with line breaks using mkString("\n"), then you will keep the line breaks.

Comment: Then it will split the text only by single lines.. then the lines that are double blank will be replaced by single blank line ?

Comment: well, actually if you are reading the lines from file, using mutable buffer (ListBuffer) which is build as you go might be the better approach.

Comment: see the update in myu answer for the "imperative" way

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with `awk`. You'll probably have to figure out a way to incorporate this in your `scala` code:

```
awk '
BEGIN { print "List(" }
/^0/ { 
    printf "  %s", "List("
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        printf "%s%s" ,q $i q,(i==NF?"":", ")
    } 
    print "),"
}
END { print ")" }' RS= FS='\n' q='"'  file
```

#### Output with your sample data (from pastebin):

```
List(
  List("0MOST PEOPLE", "0BELIEVE", "0THAT"),
  List("0IF IT", "0AINT BROKE,", "0DONT FIX IT."),
  List("0BELIEVE", "0THAT", "0IF", "0IT AINT BROKE,"),
  List("0IT"),
  List("0HAVE", "0ENOUGH", "0FEATURES YET."),
)
```

Comment: I test your code (http://ideone.com/1YqxZP), and no output, same result when I test in CYGWIN. You need do some adjusts.

Comment: @BMW The blank lines in your input data on `ideone` has white spaces in them. Fix that and re-try. Here is the [result](http://ideone.com/OHr4Vm)

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "List(" }
{ s=/^[0-9]/?1:0;i=s?i:i+1}
  s{a[i]=a[i]==""?$0:a[i] OFS $0}
END{ for (j=1;j<=i;j++)
        if (a[j]!="")
          { gsub(/\|/,"\",\"",a[j])
            printf "  list(\"%s\")\n", a[j]
          }
     print ")"
    }' OFS="|" file

List(
  list("0MOST PEOPLE","0BELIEVE","0THAT")
  list("0IF IT","0AINT BROKE,","0DONT FIX IT.")
  list("0BELIEVE","0THAT","0IF","0IT AINT BROKE,")
  list("0IT")
  list("0HAVE","0ENOUGH","0FEATURES YET.")
)
```

#### Explanation

- `s=/^[0-9]/?1:0;i=s?i:i+1` marks (s and i) are used to detect new record or not.
- `s{a[i]=a[i]==""?$0:a[i] OFS $0}` save each record (seperated by non-numbmer start line) to array `a`
- the reset in `END` is used to print out the result with expect format.
- `OFS="|"` Hope there is no char `|` in your input file, if have, please change it to other chars, such as @, # , etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Scala, but I think this is the regex you're looking for:

`([A-Z]+[A-Z ]*)`

See it in action: http://regex101.com/r/gY8lX6

Edit: / / in that case, all you need to do is add a zero to the beginning of the capture group:

`(0[A-Z]+[A-Z ]*)`

Comment: Apologies for the mistake in the output that I provided earlier. I need those zeroes too. Edited the output now. And I do not want the lines that do not start with zero (like ENGINEER or DOESNT)

Comment: You are my Regex hero. I should redirect this to a stdout